# Hibernate: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 6...)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, hql

I state that I am using Hibernate, MySQL on Mac OSX.

I read the post that concerned my problem but unfortunately I could not solve it. Below place the code in question:

```
public List<FeedMessage> getLatestFeedMessage() {
    List<FeedMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    String hql = "from (select nomeFeed, title, max(pubDate) as maxdate "
                  + "from FeedMessage group by nomeFeed) as x inner join FeedMessage as f "
                                    + "on f.nomeFeed = x.nomeFeed and f.pubDate = x.maxdate";


    System.out.println(hql);
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        messages=query.list();
    } catch (QueryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(session.isOpen())
        session.close();
    }

    return messages;

}
```

I'm trying to select from a MySQL db the first line of each group, but I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 6 [from (select nomeFeed, title, max(pubDate) as maxdate from it.unirc.fantapjam.FeedMessage.Model.FeedMessage group by nomeFeed) as x inner join FeedMessage as f on f.nomeFeed = x.nomeFeed and f.pubDate = x.maxdate]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:304)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1796)...........
```

I think the problem is that Hibernate can not translate the query because, if I run directly to MySQL, this works. Alternatively, I tried to run the sequent query:

```
String hql = "from (select nomeFeed, title, max(pubDate) as maxdate "
                                    + "from FeedMessage "
                                    + "group by nomeFeed) as x,  FeedMessage as f "
                    + "where f.nomeFeed = x.nomeFeed and f.pubDate = x.maxdate";
```

but I get the same result.

Comment: Do you try to execute SQL or HQL?..

Comment: May be you should look at method `Session.createSQLQuery(String)` instead of `Session.createQuery(String)`.

Comment: I tried both, but does not work the same.

Comment: Could you share the 2nd error and stack trace?

Comment: Note that SQL query should be started with `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot do this in HQL.  According to the hibernate documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where
>   clauses.

Whereas your subquery is in the **from** clause.  If you wish to use a subquery inside the from statement, you must use native SQL as described here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html